# Android custom button shadow

Tags: android

I intend to do this exact thing:
[image]

I tried layers as background, I even tried to do this programmatically, nothing gives me the desired look. Please help.

Comment: Add code that you've tried so far !!!

Comment: make a custom `Drawable` class and draw whatever you like in `draw()` method

Comment: but honestly simple nine patch drawable will suffice

Comment: To set icon besides Text on Button use  android:drawableLeft="@drawable/share_icon"     attribute.

Comment: ok will try a nine patch now!

Comment: well, the main problem is the shadow size, smaller than the actual button, any ideas on that?

Comment: whats the problem with shadow size?

Comment: the width of it should be smaller, I could not achieve that so far.